# Getting error in postman "Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, null, postman

Could you please help me to fix below issue?

Actually building a e-commerce website and I was testing an API's and I encounter below error while testing in postman.

Error:-"{
"error": "Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')"
}"

I lost my track and confuse please help me?
Below are the codes from different files please go through and suggest what changes needs to do.

Below is the jxt.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const generateToken = (userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: "48h" });
  return token;
};

const getUserIdFromToken = (token) => {
  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
  return decodedToken.userId;
};

module.exports = { generateToken, getUserIdFromToken };
```

Below is the Authenticate.js

```
const jwtProvider = require("../config/jwtProvider.js");
const userService = require("../services/user.services.js");

const authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: "Invalid" });
    }

    const userId = jwtProvider.getUserIdFromToken(token);
    const user = userService.findUserById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: "User not found" });
    }
    req.user = user;
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }

  next();
};

module.exports = authenticate;
```

Below is the orderController.js

```
const orderService = require("../services/order.services.js");

const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await req.user;
  try {
    let createdOrder = await orderService.createOrder(user, req.body);
    return res.status(201).send(createdOrder);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};

const findOrderById = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await req.user;
  try {
    let createdOrder = await orderService.findOrderById(req.params.id);
    return res.status(201).send(createdOrder);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};

const orderHistory = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await req.user;
  try {
    let createdOrder = await orderService.usersOrderHistory(user._id);
    return res.status(201).send(createdOrder);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createOrder,
  findOrderById,
  orderHistory,
};


"Below is the userController"

const userService = require("../services/user.services.js");

const getUserProfile = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const jwt = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];

    if (!jwt) {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: "token not found" });
    }
    const user = await userService.getUserProfileByToken(jwt);
    return res.status(200).send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};

const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await userService.getAllUsers();
    return res.status(200).send(users);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};

module.exports = { getUserProfile, getAllUsers };


"Below is the User Modal"

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: "CUSTOMER",
  },

  mobile: {
    type: String,
  },

  address: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "addresses",
    },
  ],

  paymentInformation: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "payment_information",
    },
  ],

  ratings: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "ratings",
    },
  ],
  reviews: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "reviews",
    },
  ],

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Below is the orderservices code

```
const Address = require("../models/address.model.js");
const Order = require("../models/order.model.js");
const OrderItem = require("../models/orderItems.js");
const cartService = require("../services/cart.services.js");

async function createOrder(user, shipAddress) {
  let address;
  if (shipAddress._id) {
    let existAddress = await Address.findById(shipAddress._id);
    address = existAddress;
  } else {
    address = new Address(shipAddress);
    address.user = user;
    await address.save();

    console.error(address);

    user.address.push(address);
    await user.save();
  }

  const cart = await cartService.findUserCart(user._id);
  const orderItems = [];

  for (const item of cart.cartItems) {
    const orderItem = new OrderItem({
      price: item.price,
      product: item.product,
      quantity: item.quantity,
      size: item.size,
      userId: item.userId,
      discountedPrice: item.discountedPrice,
    });
    const createdOrderItem = await orderItem.save();
    orderItems.push(createdOrderItem);
  }

  const createdOrder = new Order({
    user,
    orderItems,
    totalPrice: cart.totalPrice,
    totalDiscountedPrice: cart.totalDiscountedPrice,
    discount: cart.discount,
    totalItem: cart.totalItem,
    shipAddress: address,
  });

  const savedOrder = await createdOrder.save();
  return savedOrder;
}
async function placeOrder(orderId) {
  const order = await findOrderById(orderId);
  order.orderStatus = "PLACED";
  order.paymentDetails.status = "COMPLETED";

  return await order.save();
}

async function confirmedOrder(orderId) {
  const order = await findOrderById(orderId);
  order.orderStatus = "CONFIRMED";
  return await order.save();
}

async function shippedOrder(orderId) {
  const order = await findOrderById(orderId);
  order.orderStatus = "SHIPPED";
  return await order.save();
}

async function deliveredOrder(orderId) {
  const order = await findOrderById(orderId);
  order.orderStatus = "DELIVERED";
  return await order.save();
}

async function cancelledOrder(orderId) {
  const order = await findOrderById(orderId);
  order.orderStatus = "CANCELLED";
  return await order.save();
}

async function findOrderById(orderId) {
  const order = await Order.findById(orderId)
    .populate("user")
    .populate({ path: "orderItems", populate: { path: "product" } })
    .populate("shippingAddress");

  return order;
}

async function usersOrderHistory(userId) {
  try {
    const orders = await Order.find({
      user: userId,
      orderStatus: "PLACED",
    })
      .populate({ path: "orderItems", populate: { path: "product" } })
      .lean();
    return orders;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
}

async function getAllOrders() {
  return await Order.find()
    .populate({ path: "orderItems", populate: { path: "product" } })
    .lean();
}

async function deleteOrder(orderId) {
  const order = await findOrderById(orderId);
  await Order.findByIdAndDelete(order._id);
}

module.exports = {
  createOrder,
  placeOrder,
  confirmedOrder,
  shippedOrder,
  deliveredOrder,
  cancelledOrder,
  findOrderById,
  usersOrderHistory,
  getAllOrders,
  deleteOrder,
};

Below is the userServices code 


const User = require("../models/user.model");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwtProvider = require("../config/jwtProvider.js");

const createUser = async (userData) => {
  try {
    let { firstName, lastName, email, password } = userData;
    const isUserExist = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (isUserExist) {
      throw new Error(
        `Sorry, but a user with  email address: ${email} already exists. Please use a different email.`
      );
    }
    password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);

    const user = await User.create({ firstName, lastName, email, password });

    console.log("create user", user);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};

const findUserById = async (userId) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).populate("address");
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error(
        `User not found with userId ${userId}. Please check your user ID and try again.`
      );
    }
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};

const getUserByEmail = async (email) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error(
        `User not found with email ${email}. Please check your email ID and try again.`
      );
    }
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};

const getUserProfileByToken = async (token) => {
  try {
    const userId = jwtProvider.getUserIdFromToken(token);

    const user = await findUserById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error(
        `User not found with userId ${userId}. Please check your email ID and try again.`
      );
    }
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};

const getAllUsers = async () => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};
module.exports = {
  createUser,
  findUserById,
  getUserByEmail,
  getUserProfileByToken,
  getAllUsers,
};
```

Just try to find error. did'nt try anything different

Comment: There are 5 places where you are trying access _id property, which one gives you an error?

Comment: And once you figure that out, just work backwards to where the object variable is coming from, and figure out why it's `null`.

Comment: With this question, ^ these are your answers

Answer (score 0):

Without taking too close of a look, you should be able to use a safe navigator on your objects containing `_id`. I suspect the issue is originating from:

```
let createdOrder = await orderService.usersOrderHistory(user._id);
```

As that seems to be the place you're defining that error response format. However, all of the below have the potential to raise a similar issue in attempting to access `_id` of a `null` object.

```
if (shipAddress._id) {
```

```
const cart = await cartService.findUserCart(user._id);
```

```
await Order.findByIdAndDelete(order._id);
```

A simple fix would be to add JS's safe object accessor/navigator `?`.
Example:

```
let createdOrder = await orderService.usersOrderHistory(user?._id);
```

However, note that if whatever processes the result (in this case: `usersOrderHistory`) will potentially raise an issue if it cannot handle `null` values.

Another option would be creating an `if` guard for cases where the object of `_id` may be null:

```
if (user) {
  ...
  let createdOrder = await orderService.usersOrderHistory(user?._id);
  ...
}
```

(While not necessarily worth it for just this single case, I tend to use the `lodash` package/library for many object related operations. With this, you could do:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
...
// a default value is not 100% necessary, but if `user` does not have
// `_id` for whatever reason, then this will return `undefined`
const someDefaultValue = -1;
let createdOrder = await orderService.usersOrderHistory(_.get(user, '_id', someDefaultValue);
...
```

)